# IIS 6 - Only certain directories are being logged

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, log-files, logging

I have 3 websites on a Windows 2003 server with IIS 6. They all have the same logging options set up. (As far as I can tell) However, one of the sites is only logging 2 .NET applications, and is not logging anything else on the site, even though there are thousands of files. The other 2 sites on the server seem to be logging everything as desired. Log format on all sites is is "W3C Extended Log File Format". Any ideas what might be causing only certain things to log on the one site?

[UPDATE] I discovered that the "Log Visits" checkbox on the individual folders are unchecked. How could this have happened? Also, is there any way to enable this on all folders at once instead of doing this for each folder (IIS won't let me highlight multiple folders).

Comment: Have you verified that you can indeed pull one of the other thousands of files through http?

Comment: Yes, this is a production site that has been running fine for almost a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through and enabled the logging option every folder on the site manually. It took a while, but appears to be working now. Any ideas on what could have caused this, or an easier way to update all folders would still be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Weird...did you try unchecking log visits from the parent site, applying changes, then rechecking it?

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but it did not cascade throughout the site unfortunately.